# jQuery: hide all elements with attr=value

Tags: jquery, hide

I have multiple divs on page with data-year attribue.
Each has a value of a year.
I'm checking if any of those values in given range appears more than one.

```
for (i = 2020; i < 2025; i++) {

   let variable = $("[data-sorting=" + i + "]");

   if (variable.length > 1) {

       alert("it's more than one div! value: " + i);

   }

}
```

If it does, i want to hide/remove all of them, except just one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could hide all but the first elements in the collection within `variable`:

```js
for (i = 2020; i < 2025; i++) {
  let variable = $("[data-sorting=" + i + "]");
  if (variable.length > 1) {
    variable.not(':first').hide(); // or remove()
  }
}
```